# Restrict Generic to Basic Types

Tags: c#

I have the following method:

```
public class RangeFilter<T> : Filter<T> {
}
```

Is there a way to restrict T to the following types:

```
bool 
byte, sbyte 
char, string
decimal, double, float
int, uint, long, ulong
short, ushort
```

Comment: No, there's no base type that encompasses that list of types exclusively.  What are you going to do in the class that applies to both integers and strings?  aybe a constraint on `IComparable` is what you want?

Comment: @DStanley Those are not only numeric types!

Comment: Try `struct` and eventually some more types
    `public class RangeFilter<T> : Filter<T> where T : struct`

Comment: @KevinWallis `string` is not a `struct`

Comment: @DStanley I have mentioned that